# Unserializing a PHP object without a namespace

Tags: php, serialization, namespaces

I'm writing a new PHP application against an existing database which has been designed rather poorly.

The older application has a custom `Test` class which has been instantiated and inserted in the database, then retrieved and unserialized, etc. Obviously poor design, but it's worked for them so far.

My new application needs to be able to deserialize these objects, so I copy-pasted the old class definition to the top of the file where I use `unserialize`, but I get this error:

> The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Test" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

Since I've defined the class *before* I use it, I thought this would work. Is it a problem with namespaces? The old class definition had no namespace, but now it's in `App\Foo\Bar`. This is a Laravel project that uses autoloading.

Comment: If the app's namespace is `App\Foo\Bar`, that makes the class' name `App\Foo\Bar\Test`. Since the serialised data only specifies `Test` as the class' name, indeed, class `Test` doesn't exist. Either specify a class `Test` (global namespace), or alter your serialised data (tricky).

Comment: Here's a quick [eval.in](https://eval.in/654119) illustrating what @deceze has already pointed out. As you can see, the serialised result for each instance of `Test` is different.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, `namespace{}` was an especially helpful trick :)

Comment: @DarraghEnright the link is broken